# Grouping multiple accounts with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|    |    A    |     B     |     C      |      D      |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 1306802 | 811-23124 | S000053152 |    29532809 |
|  2 | 1306802 | 811-23124 | S000057200 |   191936604 |
|  3 | 1306802 | 811-00537 | NA         |   106393284 |
|  4 | 1306802 | 811-00537 | NA         |   105092944 |
|  5 | 1306802 | 811-00537 | NA         | 10962227335 |
|  6 | 1306802 | 811-04706 | NA         | 25249641849 |
|  7 | 1306802 | 811-04706 | NA         |           0 |
|  8 | 1306802 | 811-04706 | NA         | 23510301799 |
|  9 | 1306802 | 811-04706 | NA         |  9477889899 |
| 10 | 1306802 | 811-04894 | NA         |  2847314143 |
| 11 | 1306802 | 811-04986 | NA         |           0 |
| 12 | 1306802 | 811-04986 | NA         |   107804150 |
| 13 | 1306802 | 811-04986 | NA         |   257550681 |
| 14 | 1306802 | 811-04986 | NA         |  2712807262 |
| 15 | 1306802 | 811-04986 | NA         |  2010169002 |
| 16 | 1306802 | 811-05459 | NA         | 60121770194 |
| 17 | 1306802 | 811-05583 | NA         |  1922165752 |
| 18 | 1306802 | 811-05583 | NA         |  2259339058 |
| 19 | 1306802 | 811-05583 | NA         | 57707441184 |
| 20 | 1306802 | 811-05583 | NA         | 82371244343 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

And I need it to look like this, where A is the group, B is count of distinct values, C is count of distinct values, and D is sum.

```
+---+---------+---+---+--------------+
|   |    A    | B | C |      D       |
+---+---------+---+---+--------------+
| 1 | 1306802 | 7 | 2 | 281950622292 |
+---+---------+---+---+--------------+
```

I've tried the following but it only gives me record counts. I've also tried to use `summarize_all` and specifying column functions but I get errors.

```
result <- data.frame %>% 
    group_by(A) %>%
    summarize(n())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `across` from the `dplyr` >= 1.0.0 within `summarise` where we can have multiple blocks of columns with summarisation on different functions.  Here, the B, C is placed inside `across` and get the number of distinct values (`n_distinct`) while we get the `sum` of 'D' as well outside the `across` (after grouping by 'A')

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(A) %>%
     summarise(across(B:C, n_distinct, na.rm = TRUE), D = sum(D, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#        A     B     C            D
#    <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>
#1 1306802     7     2 281950622292
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 
1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 
1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 1306802L, 
1306802L, 1306802L), B = c("811-23124", "811-23124", "811-00537", 
"811-00537", "811-00537", "811-04706", "811-04706", "811-04706", 
"811-04706", "811-04894", "811-04986", "811-04986", "811-04986", 
"811-04986", "811-04986", "811-05459", "811-05583", "811-05583", 
"811-05583", "811-05583"), C = c("S000053152", "S000057200", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), D = c(29532809, 191936604, 106393284, 105092944, 10962227335, 
25249641849, 0, 23510301799, 9477889899, 2847314143, 0, 107804150, 
257550681, 2712807262, 2010169002, 60121770194, 1922165752, 2259339058, 
57707441184, 82371244343)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I just came across the `n_distinct` function. Does the following `summarize` do the same? `summarize(B=n_distinct(B, na.rm = T), C=n_distinct(C, na.rm =T),D=sum(D, na.rm = T)`  When would you use `across` instead of this example?

Comment: @mdute.  yes, it should work the same.   Thanks for the `na.rm` argument.  I didn't notice that.  Updated.  I would use `across` when you have more than 10 columns to do the summarise and writing 10 times the same function would takes a lot of time

Comment: @akrun ...why does this need to be in an across?

Comment: @akrun. Can you use `across` when using a custom column name? Like `X=n_distinct(B, na.rm = T)`. Or would you have to type all the columns out?

Comment: @MitchellGraham only reason being that it can be extended as a general case where as the one OP showed would be more manual in working with datasets with more features

Comment: @mdute YOu can pass anonymous function or a custom function i.e. `~na_distinct(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @mdute For e.g. if you created a function `f1 <- function(x) n_distinct(x, na.rm = TRUE)`, then it can be passed as `df1 %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(across(B:C, f1))`